# C# TabControl TabPage Change

Tags: c#, .net, tabcontrol, tabpage

How do I change the tabpage being displayed in my tabcontrol programmatically?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Either by tabControl1.SelectedIndex which is an integer or if you have a reference to a particular tab, tabControl1.SelectedTab.

If you wanted the first one selected:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: The simplest thing to do, yet I always have to look it up...my memory cells must be fading...

Comment: big tnx! I was since always do it in bad way! Tnx for this solution :)

Answer (score 10):

Other alternatives to the accepted answer:

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = MyTabPage;
```

or  `tabControl1.SelectTab("NameOfTabToActivate");`

or  `tabControl1.SelectTab(IndexOfTab);`

or  `tabControl1.SelectTab(TabObject);`

(I stole this answer from this post: [Activate tabpage of TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921224/activate-tabpage-of-tabcontrol))