# Activate TabPage of TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am using TabControl in a .NET application. By default, the first tab page of TabControl is showing in form loading. I want to show other tab pages in form loading. Programmatically, how can I show a different tab page?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = MyTab;
```

or

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages["tabName"];
```

Where `tabName` is the Name of the tab you want to activate (`tabName` is NOT the text display).

Comment: Alternatively, you may also use: **tabControl1.Select("NameOfTabToActivate");**

Comment: I have also used tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: Why is this not a property on the Property window in the designer ? That does not makes any sense, one should be able to set this in the designer not only by code.

Answer (score 46):

You can use the method `SelectTab`.

There are 3 versions:

```
public void SelectTab(int index);
public void SelectTab(string tabPageName);
public void SelectTab(TabPage tabPage);
```

Answer (score 20):

There are two properties in a TabControl control that manages which tab page is selected.

[SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) which offer the possibility to select it by index (an integer starting from 0 to the number of tabs you have minus one).

[SelectedTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx) which offer the possibility to selected the tab object itself to select.

Setting either of these property will change the currently displayed tab.

Alternatively you can also use the Select method. It comes in three flavour, one where you pass the [index of the tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdc8ebh8.aspx), another the [TabPage object itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c881zk4f.aspx) and [the last one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbt9db4b.aspx) a string representing the tab's name.

Answer (score 12):

For  Windows  Smart device   (compact frame  work ) (MC75-Motorola  devices)

```
     mytabControl.SelectedIndex = 1
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `SelectTab` like this:

```
TabPage t = tabControl1.TabPages[2];
tabControl1.SelectTab(t); //go to tab
```

Use `SelectedTab` like this:

```
TabPage t = tabControl1.TabPages[2];
tabControl1.SelectedTab = t; //go to tab
```