# How to Select Tab

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have `TabControl` and 4 `TabPages`. I need to select the second Tab programmatically!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activate tabpage of TabControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921224/activate-tabpage-of-tabcontrol)

Comment: If you did some searching there are many answers here on SO that clearly show how this is done. Here is one for example: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921224/activate-tabpage-of-tabcontrol** (look @Gimly) answer. Also a quick Google search yielded me about 630,000 hits, just a suggestion. This isn't a programming problem, this is lack of doing research before asking a good question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have two ways to do it

1. SelectedTab:

   `MyTabControl.SelectedTab = MyTabPage` (The TabPage you want to select)
2. SelectedIndex:

   `MyTabControl.SelectedIndex = 1` (1 is the index of the second TabPage)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach, I trust someone will find it helpful, using My.Settings:

**Code for the exit button/routine:**

```
    Private Sub PicClose_App_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PicClose_App.Click

    ' Save the current active tab index, this will be used on next startup to determine on which TabPage to start
    My.Settings.Main_Form_Startup_TabPage = MyTabControl.SelectedTab.TabIndex

    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

**Code called from the Load event of the main form:**

```
    Public Sub Form_Startup_TabPage()
    ' Get tab index from settings, 0 has been set as default
    Dim IntStartup_TabPage As Integer = My.Settings.Main_Form_Startup_TabPage

    ' Select the last tab used
    FrmMain.TabChar_Group_Selection.SelectedIndex = IntStartup_TabPage

End Sub
```